# 'Opt_Design Error' in Vivado when trying Run Implementation

Tags: vhdl, uart, xilinx, vivado

Trying to make a UART Transmitter to send a data from FPGA to PC; 9600 baudrate, 8-bits, no parity, 1 start & stop bit; I wrote a code with VHDL, run synthesis and simulate it in a way I like it to be. I wanted to see it with BASYS 3 FPGA, After created constraints, Run Implementation issued an error in which its called "Opt_Design Error".

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


entity rs232_omo is
generic(clk_max:integer:=10400); --for baudrate


port(

clk : in std_logic;
rst : in std_logic;
start : in std_logic;
input : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
done : out std_logic;
output : out std_logic;
showstates: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end entity;

architecture dataflow of rs232_omo is

type states is (idle_state,start_state,send_state,stop_state);
signal present_state,next_state : states;
signal data,data_next : std_logic;

begin

process(clk,rst)
variable count : integer range 0 to clk_max;
variable index : integer range 0 to 10;
begin

if rst='1' then
    present_state<=idle_state;
    count:=0;
    data<='1';
    done<='0';

elsif rising_edge(clk) then

    present_state<=next_state;
    count:=count+1;
    index:=index+1;
    data<=data_next;

end if;

end process;

process(present_state,data,clk,rst,start)
variable count : integer range 0 to clk_max;
variable index : integer range 0 to 10;
begin

done<='0';
data_next<='1';

case present_state is

    when idle_state =>
        showstates<="1000";
        data_next<='1';

        if start='1' and rst='0' then
            count:=count+1;
            if count=clk_max then
                next_state<=start_state;
                count:=0;
            end if;    
        end if;

    when start_state =>
        showstates<="0100";
        data_next<='0';

        count:=count+1;
        if count=clk_max then
            next_state<=send_state;
            count:=0;
        end if;

    when send_state =>
        showstates<="0010";
        count:=count+1;
        data_next<=input(index);

        if count=clk_max then
            if index=7 then
                index:=0;
                next_state<=stop_state;
            else
                index:=index+1;
            end if;
        count:=0;
        end if;

    when stop_state =>
        showstates<="0001";
        count:=count+1;
        if count=clk_max then
        next_state<=idle_state;
        done<='1';
        count:=0;
        end if;

   end case;
   end process;
   output<=data;

   end architecture;
```

This's the error message in detail

> "[DRC MDRV-1]Multiple Driver Nets:Net done_OBUF has multiple drivers:
>   done_OBUF_inst_i_1/O,and done_reg/Q"
>
> "[Vivado_Tcl 4-78] Error(s) found during DRC. Opt_Design not run."

What would be the reason for this error?

Comment: std_logic (e.g. out port done) is a resolved data type, one or more drivers undergo resolution to determine the value. Multiple drivers aren't compatible with Xilinx FPGA architectures and it's checked (the DRC error).  The solution is to drive done from only one process, each process with an assignment to a signal has a driver for that signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `done` both in the first and the second `process`, which is exactly what the implementation is complaining about, you cannot have multiple drivers.

Remove `done<='0';` from the first process and it should complete the implementation.

(I didn't check if the rest of the code is doing exactly what you want.)